# Find a specific table and column value across all databases

Tags: sql-server, system-tables, system-databases

This is a question about logic that could help me understand more how to iterate into my DBs.

On my server I have several AdventureWorks* databases:

[image]

I have a query that cold help me iterate through all my databases, AdventureWorks* and not:

```
CREATE TABLE #LIst_DB (name nvarchar(128))

INSERT INTO #LIst_DB 

select name from  sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4
AND state = 0;

select * from #LIst_DB

DROP TABLE #LIst_DB
```

For each AdventureWorks* database I want to list `AWBuildVersion` next to each DB:

[image]

At this point I'm puzzled because there are 2 problems I don't know how to solve:

1. How to run a `select [Database Version] from AWBuildVersion` for each database?
2. What to do if a database has no `AWBuildVersion` table?

[Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17958.find-a-table-on-a-sql-server-across-all-databases.aspx) I found this query:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = stuff((
            SELECT '
UNION
SELECT ' + quotename(NAME, '''') + ' as Db_Name, Name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as Table_Name
FROM ' + quotename(NAME) + '.sys.tables WHERE NAME =  @TableName '
            FROM sys.databases
            ORDER BY NAME
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,type
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 8, '')

--PRINT @SQL;

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL
    ,N'@TableName varchar(30)'
    ,@TableName = 'AWBuildVersion'
```

That brings me close to my goal but it shows me the table name `AWBuildVersion` while I need the column Database Version = 11.0.2100.60

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments inline:

```
-- The table to find
DECLARE @find nvarchar(257) = N'dbo.AWBuildVersion';

-- Holds results
DECLARE @results table 
(
    [Db_Name] sysname PRIMARY KEY,
    [Database Version] nvarchar(25) NOT NULL
);

-- Current database   
DECLARE @db sysname;

-- AdventureWorks databases cursor
DECLARE dbs CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT D.[name] 
FROM sys.databases AS D
WHERE 
    D.[name] LIKE N'AdventureWorks%'
    AND D.state_desc = N'ONLINE'
    AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(D.[name], 'Collation') IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    D.[name];

OPEN dbs;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    -- Next database
    FETCH dbs INTO @db;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;

    -- Find [Database Version] if @find table exists
    INSERT @results ([Db_Name], [Database Version])
    EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql
        N'
            -- Construct 3-part object name
            DECLARE @object nvarchar(386) = 
                QUOTENAME(@db) + N''.'' +
                ISNULL(QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@find, 2)), '''') + N''.'' +
                QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@find, 1));

            -- Query to find [Database Version]
            DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N''
                SELECT 
                    Db_Name = '''''' + @db + '''''',
                    [Database Version] 
                FROM '' + @object;

            IF OBJECT_ID(@object, N''U'') IS NOT NULL
                EXECUTE (@sql)',
        N'@db sysname, @find nvarchar(257)',
        @db = @db, @find = @find;
END;

CLOSE dbs; DEALLOCATE dbs;

SELECT
    R.[Db_Name],
    [Table_Name] = @find,
    R.[Database Version]
FROM @results AS R
ORDER BY
    R.[Db_Name];
```

Answer (score 4):

I would not want to do that with T-SQL because it limits me in the amount of servers I could get the results from.

Instead I would create a PowerShell script like this:

```
$servers = @( 'server1', 'server2')

$query = "SELECT [Database Version] AS DatabaseVersion FROM [dbo].[AWBuildVersion];"

$results = @()
$comment = @()

# Loop through the servers
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $databases = Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $server | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'AdventureWorks*'}
    Write-Host "Going through server $server"

    # Loop through the databases
    foreach ($database in $databases) {
        # Reset variables
        $result = @()
        $data = $null
        $comment = $null

        if ($database.Tables.Name -contains 'AWBuildVersion') {
            Write-Host "- Querying database $database"

            $data = Invoke-DbaSqlQuery -SqlInstance $server -Database $database.Name -Query $query 
        }
        else {
            $comment += 'Could not find table AWBuildVersion'
        }

        $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Server          = $server
            Database        = $database.Name
            DatabaseVersion = $data.DatabaseVersion
            Comment         = $comment -join ', '
        }

        $results += $result
    }
}

$results
```

[image: result of the script]

You do need the [dbatools powershell module](https://dbatools.io/download/) to run it.

What it does is:

- Iterates through the servers you assign.
- Retrieves the databases that have 'AdventureWorks' in the name.
- Iterates through the databases and executes the query.
- If it cannot find the table it adds a comment to the results that the table could not be found.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but the results are not formatted like in your picture. Do you know how I can format the result in the same 3 columns 

|Server|Database|DatabaseVersion|

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get a different result. I executed the script on my machines and was able to get the same result as in the picture.
I did remove a line of code that generated an error. Can you send me a printscreen of what the result is on your machine?

Comment: they get formatted differently if you point it against just one server. Interesting. The code is brilliant and it works, I still have a few problem connecting to a remote server because I'm not administrator but I think I can sort it out

Comment: Connecting to local-host is fine, connecting to remote servers is still a pain `WARNING: [Invoke-DbaSqlQuery][17:43:26] Failure | Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user....`. I added `-SqlCredential (Get-Credential sa)` so it prompts me the login, i enter the password but then it gives me again the same error because is trying to login with `MYDOMAIN\username` instead of `sa\password`

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use `sp_foreachDB` contained in Brent Ozar's [First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_foreachdb.sql):

```
EXEC dbo.sp_foreachDB @command1 = 'select [Database Version] from dbo.AWBuildVersion', 
                 @name_pattern = 'AdventureWorks%'
```

Haven't tested this but I believe the syntax should work.

Comment: tested, is not working: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'AWBuildVersion'`.

Comment: I don't have all those AW DBs handy right now..this is some troubleshooting  I believe you can take on yourself.